# Applying multiple attributes for the OutputCache

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, outputcache

i have the following search action method, currently i am applying the cache to only one search parameter which is causing some false results incase the user change the q2 or q3 parameters while keeping the same value for the q paramter so the search result will return the same search results regardless of the q2 and q3 values, so i need to apply the cache for the three search parameters together,, so how i can do so?

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "long", VaryByParam = "q")]
        public PartialViewResult Search(string q, int q2,string q3,string sortOrder)
        {
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
[OutputCache(CacheProfile = "long", VaryByParam = "q;q2;q3")]
```

Use a semicolon-separated list for your parameters.

[OutputCacheAttribute.VaryByParam Property MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.outputcacheattribute.varybyparam.aspx)